# Передать изображение с камеры на другой ViewController Swift

Tags: swift, камера, передача-данных, uiviewcontroller

Начал изучать работу с камерой на swift и хотелось бы получить от вас помощи.

Камера открывается с помощью кнопки на главном ViewController, после снимка, нужно передать полученное изображение с камеры в другой ViewController "MasterPhotoPost"

Получаю изображение с камеры в переменную:

```swift
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        var image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        //imagePicked.image = image
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: showMasterPost)
    }
```

Вот код окна MasterPhotoPost:

```swift
class MasterPhotoPost: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var imagePicked: UIImageView!

    var image: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicked.image = image
    }
}
```

Каким способом можно передать полученное изображение в MasterPhotoPost? 
Так как я новичок ещё в Swift, просьба помочь кодом. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Если можно покажите как реализован `showMasterPost`

Comment: @schmidt9
`func showMasterPost(){
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialVC = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MasterPhotoPost")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.getTopMostViewController()?.present(initialVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        var image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        //imagePicked.image = image
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: showMasterPost(image))
    }

    func showMasterPost(_ image: UIImage){ 
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
        let initialVC = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MasterPhotoPost") 
        initialVC.image = image
        self.getTopMostViewController()?.present(initialVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Но появилась теперь ошибка в строке `imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: showMasterPost(image))`

**Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?'**
Буду разбираться)

Comment: @nekogan это потому что блок в completion не может принимать параметры, пардон моя ошибка. Вы можете присвоить `image` глобальной переменной  и затем обратиться к ней в `showMasterPost`

Comment: Огромнейшая благодарность за такую помощь! Теперь всё работает как надо. Вы лучший)

Comment: @nekogan ахах спасибо и удачи в изучении языка